# Section View in Windows8 Listview?

Tags: windows, windows-8

How can i implement a Section View(like in IOS) in Windows8 ListView ?
I want to break down the Listview into different Sections.

Any Directions ?

Comment: They are called "groups" in ListView.

Answer (score 1):

ListViews have a property called `groupDataSource` that lets you define how the items are grouped. You might want to look at the **Grid App** template in Visual Studio, which has data already set up in this way. You can also take a look at this tutorial: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh465464.aspx

If you want any more info, you will have to be a bit more specific with your line of questioning.

Answer (score 0):

In my [Netflix post](http://www.codefoster.com/post/2012/06/13/netflixstage1.aspx) on [codefoster.com](http://www.codefoster.com) I tried to show grouping in its simplest form. When you have a JS array, you simply make a Binding.List out of it and then you just call createGrouped sending it two lambda functions telling it how to group. Then like @Paul said, you'll get those different sections automatically in your ListView. Hope that helps.